# Delphi deletes iOS64 binary from compiled folder after linking

Tags: ios, delphi, compilation, firemonkey, executable

I'm having troubles on Rad studio 10.3.2 and iOS 13.1

Delphi systematically deletes the binary from the `iOSDevice6` debug folder after linking and gives me a compiling succeeded message.

Then at the deploy phase it gives me an error message saying the binary is missing....

I managed to install an empty project on my phone, so there is no problem with the provisioning and so on. Also the project option has the same settings as the empty app.

Please help.

Comment: Many years ago I had a similar issue in a Java project where after compilation one of the generated .class files went missing. When packaged in a jar archive, the app wouldn't work. Turned out it was the virus scanner that identified the class file (false positive) as hazardous and quarantined it seconds after it was created. You should check your virus scanner logs...

Answer (score 0):

well, after some tinkering I managed to resolve the issue, so for anyone having this issue, rename the $(MODULENAME) to your binary name.